# Unable to alias ThunkDispatch as generic

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to make my typing in my redux actions cleaner. The first line below works fine, but the second one gives me an error on  saying `Type T doesn't satisfy the constraint Action

```
type MyThunkAction =  ThunkAction<void, AppState, {}, MyAction> // MyAction is any of the action types I've defined, as a union type
type MyThunkDispatch<T> =  ThunkDispatch<AppState, {}, T>
```

I'm able to use that basic signature in typing the dispatch inline:

```
   async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<AppState, {}, ChangeAction | ErrorAction>) => { // ChangeAction is the specific action type expected in this function
```

How can I alias the `ThunkDispatch` type the way I want to?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you'd need to make it `<T extends Action>`.

Also, I showed some examples of declaring a reusable thunk type in [the Redux Starter Kit "Advanced Tutorial" docs page](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/tutorials/advanced-tutorial):

```
// rootReducer.ts
const rootReducer = combineReducers({})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>

// store.ts
import rootReducer, { RootState } from './rootReducer'

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch

export type AppThunk = ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, Action<string>>
```

In your case, you could make it `AppThunk<T extends Action> = ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, T>`.

Comment: Thanks...writing `T extends Action` (with Action imported from redux) gives `ESLint Parsing Error: '?' expected.` So that's weird... (when I add the `?` I still get that error. still weird)

Comment: My TS syntax is still kinda shaky, but some form of `extends Action` should be the right idea.